# listview and fetch react native not working

Tags: javascript, json, listview, fetch

I'm trying to load info from a json file using fetch and displaying data using a Listview React native component. Data from fetch is already load on my this.state.films, because if I try

```
<Text>{this.state.films[0].title}</Text>
```

I get the name of the film and that is ok. But when I try a Listview I only get "[]". 
What am I doing wrong?? Actually I'm following React native doc and I am trinying to join two sections: "Networking" and "Using a list view". I took json from there.
Please Help, 
Thanks!

That my code index.windows.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { films: [] }
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((movies) => {
        this.setState({ films: ds.cloneWithRows(movies.movie) })
      })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={{paddingTop: 22}}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.films}
            renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.title}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      );
    } 

}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native has a simpler solution, a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), which works nicely, and wraps around the ListView. It can be used like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {

  state = { 
    films: [] 
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then( response => response.json())
      .then((films) => {
        this.setState({ films })
      })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={{paddingTop: 22}}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.films}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      );
    } 

}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```